# Reinstalling windows 10 on bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-utility

I had bootcamp with windows 10 running nicely on my MacBook Pro 2016, until one day a windows 10 update caused the virtual machine to misbehave, freeze, show black screens. Startuprepair, DISM, trying to reinstall windows 10 from inside the OS - all didn't work and were giving me errors.

So I finally decided to start from scratch with a new bootcamp. I wiped the bootcamp partition using disk utility. Then I tried to use Bootcamp assistant to restore to single partition, but it was giving me an error as well. So I went to disk utility and formatted the partition. I wanted to remove it, so that I have only one partition and and start from scratch with Bootcamp, but disk utility isn't allowing me too.

So I'm furthur done the rabbit hole and not sure what to do. I have a 90GB paritition sitting on my disk not doing anything. I just want to get windows through bootcamp installed on it again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this advice as per link:
http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/09/remove-windows-boot-camp-partition-mac/

Before trying out:
1. Please backup your Mac OS X files first as a precaution.